# How to do B-Tree Insert

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

I am trying to insert 3 values into this B-Tree, 60, 61, and 62. I understand how to insert values when a node is full, and has an empty parent, but what if the parent is full?

For example, when I insert 60 and 61, that node will now be full. I can't extend the parent, or the parent of the parent (because they are full). So can I change the values of the parent? I have provided an image of the B-tree prior to my insert, and after.

[image: Before insert of 60, 61, 62]
Attempt to insert 60, 61, 62:
[image: After]
Notice I changed the 66 in the root to 62, and added 62 to to the <72 node. Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the insertion you've done, you get what's normally referred to as a B* tree. In a "pure" B-tree, the insertion when the root is full would require splitting the current root into two nodes, and creating a new root node above them (B-tree implementations do not require that root node to follow the same rule as other nodes for the minimum number of descendants, so having only two would be allowed).

Comment: Ok, so let me make sure I understand what you are saying. Basically I am going to create a new root node and have it lead to 2 new nodes - one containing [26|41| | ] and another containing [66|87| | ]. And from there I insert the 62 by shifting the 66|87 to the right one slot and creating a new range?

Comment: The current root node gets split into two, one containing 26 and 41, and the other containing 66 and 87. The 62 then goes into the new root node (note that it's coincidental that the newly inserted value goes in the new root -- the root should contain the median of the values in the previous root along with the value being inserted.